# When Mouse over To div selector I want to bring the background image to the div in jquery

Tags: jquery

When Mouse over To div selector  I want to bring the background image to the div in jquery. Here I am facing problem in anchor tag. In anchor tag I called the image.so when I mouse over to img attribute ,The jquery image is not visible , Instead of image if I give text , the jquery brings the background image to the div.You can see my code

```
Here is my html:
<div class="productnew">
<a href="#"><img src="img/dynamic/girlsproduct-01.png" ></a>
</div><!--end of productnew--> 

Here is my jquery:
$(function()
{
$('.productnew').hover(function(){
//alert('ok');
$('.productnew').css('background-image','url("img/dynamic/boysproducts-01.png") no-repeat');
});
});
```

Comment: It's not clear what you asking for, to get an answer here please explain properly what is your goal and what is your issue?

Comment: just mouse hover I want to bring background image to the product new div

Comment: Call you help me..please. I have given my code clearly what I am trying to do. background image is not coming

Comment: Ya sure you can get help, but so background image would be covered(hidden) by `<img src="...">`. Right?

Comment: Absolutely correct. You got that ? instead of image If i put any text in anchor tag the background image is coming.trigger our and update the code please

Comment: What happen, have tried at your end...please update me

Answer (score 1):

Try it : Change your jquery code as per below ... may be it help to you

```
$(function()
    {
            $('.productnew').mouseover(function () {
                    //alert('ok');
                    $('.productnew a img').attr('src', 'img/dynamic/boysproducts-01.png');
                });
                $('.productnew').mouseout(function () {
                    //alert('ok');
                    $('.productnew a img').attr('src', 'img/dynamic/girlsproduct-01.png');
                });
    });
```